# Optimal SQL query to check what rows in one large table don't exist in another even larger table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

Setup: SQL Server Developer Edition running on computer with i9, 32Gb RAM, and 2TB NVMe SSd.

I have a database on table1 there is around ~350,000,000 rows. There is only one column (for simplicity call it table1column). It's `varchar(100)`. It's also has a non-clustered index.

I have a second table on same db that is ~400,000 records. There is also only one column on it (call it table2column) It's `varchar(50)`. It's also has a non-clustered index.

The question: given the large sizes of both tables what is the optimal query to retrieve a list of records in table2 (the one with 400K records) that **don't** exist in table1?

Comment: One might add a [filtered index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15) to `table1` that only contains `table1column` values with `Len( table1column ) <= 50`. Depending on the distribution of values that might provide a considerably smaller index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `not exists`:

```
select t2.table2column
from table2 t2
where not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.table1column = t2.table2column)
```

This query should be able to take advantage of the existing indexes on both tables.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've been given contradictory answers so I'm going to test both methods and post the results here.